# Uber app is working for only developer accounts

Tags: uber-api

My app is ready for Live environment, when i try to login on uber account with user that is not added under developers section in Uber API after login user get invalid_scope error.

I am using live URL for login

Comment: What is the URL you use to authenticate the user? My assumption is that the url could be invalid. Hence, the scope error.

Answer (score 1):

When you're ready to open up your app to a larger audience and go into production, please submit a request for Full Access and provide adequate material showing the Uber API integration. Steps to Request Full Access

1) Sign In to the Developer Dashboard using an Uber account.
2) Click the Authorization tab
3) Click Request Full Access next to the privileged scope
4) Provide as much information about your app as possible
5) Submit the request

Find out more in the scopes docs: https://developer.uber.com/docs/rides/scopes